# Changing text in txt file with .BAT

Tags: batch-file

My program is almost working but I need some help with the way the content in the .txt files are updating. My program might be messy or sloppy, I am not a good programmer and I have been copying and pasting logic from this website until things started working!!

Program logic step by step

1.Copy all .csv files from folder1 to folder2

2.Delete all existing .txt files in folder2

3.Convert all .csv files in folder2 to .txt files

4.Change data in each .txt file

**Before data in txt file**

```
.001

.002

.004
```

**Desired  After data in txt file**

```
Input1=.001

Input2=.002

Input3=.004
```

**Actual  After data in txt file**

```
.001

.002

.004

Input1=.001

Input2=.002

Input3=.004
```

I cannot have it append to the bottom of the .txt file I need it to overwrite the existing data.

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
@echo off
set folder1="Z:\CNC_Dev\EJV\Set Up Info"
set folder_1=Z:\CNC_Dev\EJV\Set Up Info
set folder2="Z:\CNC_Dev\EJV\PW991tetsingbat"
set folder_2=Z:\CNC_Dev\EJV\PW991tetsingbat
set fType=*.csv
set fType2=*.txt
set LineNumber=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b /s "%folder_1%\%fType%"') do (
    xcopy /e /i /v /h /k /y "%%f" "%folder2%\" 2>nul
)
pause

del /s %folder2%\%fType2%
PAUSE

FOR /R "%folder2%" %%f IN (*.csv) DO REN "%%f" *.txt
PAUSE

@FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%folder_2%\*.txt"') DO (
    set /a "idx+=1"
    set "FileName[!idx!]=%%~nxf"
    set "FilePath[!idx!]=%%~dpFf"
)
PAUSE

for /L %%i in (1,1,%idx%) do (
    echo "!FileName[%%i]!"
    pause
    set LineNumber=0
    del "%TEMP%\!FileName[%%i]!.tmp" 2>nul

    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%folder_2%\!FileName[%%i]!") do (
        set /A LineNumber+=1
        echo INPUT!LineNumber!=%%I
    ) >>"%folder2%\!FileName[%%i]!"
    pause
)

echo DONE!
PAUSE
```

Comment: Your double quoting is somehow inconsequential. You should it use overall, the xcopy encloses a string already containing double quotes in the destination. The stacked `for /f` outputs appending to a file `) >>"%folder2%\!FileName[%%i]!"` where it should replace, only possible if not the same file you are just reading from.

Comment: Thank you LotPings! I'm not sure what you mean about double quoting, but I understand now that the file is not allow to override its self. Thanks again!

Comment: Interesting: you prepare to use a temporary file (`del "%TEMP%\!FileName[%%i]!.tmp" 2>nul`), but then don't use it (`) >>"%folder2%\!FileName[%%i]!"` should be `) >>"%folder2%\!FileName[%%i]!.tmp"`, followed by `ren "%folder2%\!FileName[%%i]!.tmp" "!FileName[%%i]!" after the inner loop.